# Use esbuild-loader for webpack and typescript while also using type declaration files in project?

Tags: typescript, webpack, esbuild

I'm looking to switch from `ts-loader` to `esbuild-loader` in webpack to improve build times / watch compile times.

In our project, we use various type delceration files `.d.ts` to load types/interfaces etc. However running the `esbuild-loader` get a bunch of errors around them like....

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../../interfaces/some-d-ts-file' in 'some-tsx-file.tsx'
```

Specifically in the code complaining about this...

`import { SomeInterfaces } from "../../../../../../../modules/something/interfaces";`

Which is an `interface.d.ts` file

I believe it is due to this caveat in ESBuild ? https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#no-type-system

Is there anyway to get around this? Does it require just removing all references to these `.d.ts` files ? Is there some task/compiling I can do with TS prior to esbuild-loader to fix it or some options to avoid this?

In my `webpack.config.js` I am loading the esbuild-loader like such...

```
  {
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: "esbuild-loader",
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    options: {
      target: "es6",
      loader: "tsx"
    }
  },
```

Comment: I had same issue today, I used declarationDir field in tsconfig. I thought the problem is related to it, but it seems not.
Thanks for the link, I did not know about it!